Plot fill graph Chart.js with vertical edges
I need to plot series with vertical edges. But it seems duplicate x may confuse chart.js so it does not render correct plot.
My current approach is slightly modify the x to make them different. However, I'm not very satisfy with the 11.999999 in my code. So i believe there should be some better way to express the vertical edge. And i want to know what is the correct way to plot it.


const TASKS = [
  { start: 6.5, end: 23.5, value: 17 },
  { start: 0, end: 12, value: 8 },
  { start: 12, end: 23.5, value: 23 },
  { start: 0, end: 6.5, value: 1 },
  { start: 23.5, end: 24, value: 6 },
];
const COLORS = ["#80dfff80", "#ff80df80", "#dfff8080", "#e5d29980", "#99e5d280"];

function formatTasks(tasks, epsilon) {
  const xValues = [...new Set(tasks.flatMap(task => [task.start, task.end, Math.max(0, task.start - epsilon), task.end - epsilon]))].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const result = tasks.map(task => xValues.map(x => ({
    x,
    y: x >= task.start && x < task.end ? task.value : 0
  })));
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

; [0, 1e-6].forEach((EPSILON, chartIndex) => {
  new Chart('chart' + (chartIndex + 1), {
    "type": "scatter",
    "data": {
      "labels": [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23" ],
      "datasets": formatTasks(TASKS, EPSILON).map((data, index) => ({
          "type": "scatter",
          "label": "Task " + (index + 1),
          "yAxisID": "y",
          "showLine": true,
          "pointRadius": 0,
          "pointHoverRadius": 0,
          "borderWidth": 0,
          "borderColor": "transparent",
          "pointStyle": "rect",
          "backgroundColor": COLORS[index],
          "stack": "tasks",
          "fill": index ? "-1" : "origin",
          "data": data,
      })),
    },
    "options": {
      "responsive": true,
      "maintainAspectRatio": false,
      "animation": false,
      "plugins": {
        "legend": {
          "position": "bottom",
          "labels": {
            "usePointStyle": true
          }
        },
      },
      "scales": {
        "x": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 24,
          "ticks": {
            "minRotation": 0,
            "maxRotation": 0,
            "stepSize": 1
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "type": "linear",
          "position": "left",
          "beginAtZero": true,
          "stacked": true,
          "ticks": {
            "format": {
              "maximumFractionDigits": 0
            }
          }
        },
      }
    }
  })
});
.chart-container { position: relative; margin: auto; height: 40vh; width: 80vw; min-height: 200px; }
Chart 1: (Epsilon = 0) This does not work
<div class="chart-container"><canvas id="chart1"></canvas></div>
Chart 2: (Epsilon = 1e-6) This works, but a bit ugly
<div class="chart-container"><canvas id="chart2"></canvas></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>




Your code in the first example doesn't produce repeated x values; it works if you add stepped: true option to the datasets, jsFiddle. If you did have repeated x values, indeed, chart.js doesn't discern between two values with the same x when computing stacks.

However, the epsilon solution is perfectly natural; the actual value of epsilon has to be chosen with care, but that's an issue only in the newer versions of chart.js where a value of epsilon that is too small interferes with fill computations (see jsFiddle).

An alternative solution would be to also include stacking computations in your data preparation, and not use chart.js stacking, as in this fiddle.
